# How to update the version of a package in Deploy->Package Registry of gitlab

Tags: python, gitlab, version, gitversion

I have a static version in `pyproject.toml`, I want the version to be dynamic, everytime when I deploy the latest version I want to update the version of the package automatically instead of changing it manually. Is there any way to do that?

I tried using `setuptools-git-versioning` but I could'nt succeed in doing this.

my `pyproject.toml` looks like this:

```
[build-system\]
requires = \["setuptools\>=61.0", "wheel", "setuptools-git-versioning\<2",\]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[tool.setuptools-git-versioning\]
enabled = true

[project]
name = "my-package"
dynamic = ["version"]
```

and deploy job in `.gitlab-ci.yml` looks like this:

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy-package
  image: <docker_image?
  script:
    - pip install build twine
    - pip install setuptools-git-versioning==1.13.5
    - python -m build
    - TWINE_PASSWORD=${CI_JOB_TOKEN} TWINE_USERNAME=gitlab-ci-token python -m twine upload --repository-url ${PROJECT_URL}${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/pypi dist/*
```

I wanted to know am I missing anything or is there any better way to do this?